# column not getting attached to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using the below code to do groupby calaculation.

```
**Input**
ORG DSTN    FLAG
LON SIN      Y
ADL SIN      N
SIN LON      N
LON SIN      Y
LON SIN      N
ADL SIN      Y
ADL SIN      N
SIN LON      Y
SIN LON      Y
SIN LON      Y
SIN LON      N
LON SIN      N
```

**My Code**

```
data.assign(Lane_Score=data.groupby(['ORIGIN_CITY','DEST_CITY']).Delay_Flag.apply(lambda x:x.replace('YES|NO',(x=='YES').mean(),regex=True)))
```

I am getting  the output by its not getting attached to dataframe.When I try to extract that column alone its not working.

```
data['Lane_Score']
```

How to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to pandas documentation [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

> keywords are the column names. If the values are callable, they are computed on the DataFrame and assigned to the new columns. **The callable must not change input DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).** If the values are not callable, (e.g. a Series, scalar, or array), they are simply assigned.

So you either need to assign it to original df or use explicit general assignment, Also you don't need `replace` use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform):

```
df['Lane_Score'] = df.groupby(['ORG','DSTN']).FLAG.transform(lambda x: (x=='Y').mean())
```

Or Faster approach would be:

```
df['Lane_Score'] = df['FLAG']=='Y'
df['Lane_Score'] = df.groupby(['ORG','DSTN']).Lane_Score.transform('mean')
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(Lane_Score=df.groupby(['ORG','DSTN']).FLAG.apply(lambda x: x.replace('Y|N',(x=='Y').mean(),regex=True)))
```

---

```
print(df)
    ORG DSTN FLAG  Lane_Score
0   LON  SIN    Y    0.500000
1   ADL  SIN    N    0.333333
2   SIN  LON    N    0.600000
3   LON  SIN    Y    0.500000
4   LON  SIN    N    0.500000
5   ADL  SIN    Y    0.333333
6   ADL  SIN    N    0.333333
7   SIN  LON    Y    0.600000
8   SIN  LON    Y    0.600000
9   SIN  LON    Y    0.600000
10  SIN  LON    N    0.600000
11  LON  SIN    N    0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data['Lane_Score'] = data.groupby(['ORIGIN_CITY','DEST_CITY']).Delay_Flag.apply(lambda x:x.replace('YES|NO',(x=='YES').mean(),regex=True)))
```